# i tried this but my answer came 0.00 in every input

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

[The series:-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaeLh.jpg) 
I want to write a python program in which we can can input the the value of x and n and solve this series.
can anyone help me please?
**The Series:- x-x^2+x^3/3-x^4/4+...x^n/n**

```
x = int (input ("Enter value of x: "))
numbed = int (input ("Enter value of n: "))
summed = 0

for a in range (numbed + 1) :
    if a%2==0:
        summed += (x**a)/numbed
    else:
        summed -= (x**a)/numbed
print ("Sum of series", summed)
```

**I tried this code, but no matter what values I enter, the output is always 0.00. **

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
x = int(input("Enter value of x: "))
n = int(input("Enter value of n: "))
total = x

for i in range(2, n+1):
    if i%2==0:
        total -= x**i/i
    else:
        total += x**i/i
        
print("Sum: ", total)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! My answer came with this code.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the series you mentioned in your question is this:   x - x^2/2 + x^3/3 - x^4/4 +... x^n/n.

If yes, try this:

```
x = int (input ("Enter value of x: "))
    numbed = int (input ("Enter value of n: "))
    sum1 = x
    
    for i in range(2,numbed+1):
        if i%2==0:
            sum1=sum1-((x**i)/i)
        else:
            sum1=sum1+((x**i)/i)
    print("The sum of series is",round(sum1,2))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! My answer came with this code.

Answer (score 0):

just as an example of using recurcion:

```
x = int(input("Enter value of x: "))
n = int(input("Enter value of n: "))

def f(x,n,i=1,s=1):
    return 0 if i>n else x**i/i*s + f(x,n,i+1,-s)

f(3,5)  # 35.85
```